# If there is only one hardware stack or stack register, how is it possible for multiple processes to maintain independent stacks?

Tags: stack, cpu-architecture

I'm having trouble comprehending the concept of stacks. My point is how can a single stack register be used by multiple processes? Is there any other type of stacks?

Comment: The stack is flushed to memory/CPU cache when the active process/thread is about to switch context.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a single CPU system (single core, no hyperthreading etc...), what makes this possible is [context switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) - the values of all registers are saved in memory and are switched out with those of a different process.

Comment: Is the memory ram or the cache?

Comment: Depends on the system, but usually in the CPU cache.